# heroku does not load jquery on https

Tags: javascript, python, html, heroku, highcharts

i have an app deployed to heroku and i request the jquery to be loaded

```
<script src="//www.highcharts.com/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in order to use highcharts. But when running my app on http the charts are not loaded,whereas when running the app on http the charts are loaded.

the message when running on https is:

"but requested an insecure script 'http://www.highcharts.com/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

how can i safely load jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

www.highcharts.com doesn't seem to support HTTPS, so you'll need to load jQuery from somewhere else.

Try one of the options here: http://code.jquery.com/. Or you could download the copy of jQuery you're using and just include it in your app.

**EDIT**

Further explanation: when you load https://www.highcharts.com/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js (you can try it in the browser), you get redirected to http://www.highcharts.com/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js. So the browser is ultimately loading the script from an HTTP source. You need to load from an HTTPS source.

Comment: Many many many thanks. This solved my issue.
i used 
" <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"